# Is it possible to design items in landscape on a view oriented in portrait?

Tags: ios, swift, landscape-portrait

I'll go straight to the point:
is it possible to set items like in this screen?

[image: rotated views]

Thanks to everybody.

___________EDIT____________

It works as @the4kman suggested, thanks to him!
But now I have another problem: I wanted to set it @IBDesignable with this custom class:

@IBDesignable
class MySegControl: UISegmentedControl {

```
@IBInspectable var angle: CGFloat = .pi/2

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setAngle(value: angle)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setAngle(value: angle)

}

func setAngle(value: CGFloat) {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: value)
}
```

}

but it returns me these errors in storyboard:

1) IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for TableChartViewController (npn-qh-Cnq): The agent crashed

2) IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent crashed

can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:)` to rotate views by 90 degrees:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
```

Comment: The auto layout crashes are well-known bugs and sadly, you can't do much about them.